# How to find the terraform local name for an instance?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

So,  for example assume there are two instances deployed using terraform with the below configuration.

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance1" {
      ami           =  "ami-09a4a9ce71ff3f20b"
      instance_type = "t2.micro"
      key_name = "key"
    }

resource "aws_instance" "instance2" {
  ami           =  "ami-09a4a9ce71ff3f20b"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name = "key"
}
```

I have to change the instance type of one of the instances and I know the instance ID of the instance I want to change.
In the absence of the state file how do I find the terraform local instance name using the instance ID? or can we find it with some other information?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the absence of the state file"? Is there a reason you can't access the state file but can make this change?

Comment: Ok. So, I have to make these changes for someone else and I have access to their config files through git. But as far as I know storing state file in git is not a good idea. Hence, the absence of state file.

Comment: The state is the only place that records the relationship between Terraform's own addresses like `aws_instance.instance1` and remote identifiers like `i-abc1234`. If you don't have access to the state then you'll need to request that information from someone who does. Usually we try to give our resources meaningful names _in the Terraform address_ so that we can make decisions based on that rather than based on the opaque instance ids.